# Index out of range exception when using this query from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using a calculation in my SQL query. How can I use that calculated field in C#? When I try, I get an *index out of range* exception.

My query is:

```
 Select OwnerCompanyLog.olog_name,inlt_companyid,inlt_childcompid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_percent,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares,inlt_childbase,inlt_effdate,
   ((inlt_percent * inlt_effectinterest)/100)eff
    from InterestLogTable 
    INNER JOIN OwnerCompanyLog 
    ON 
    InterestLogTable.inlt_childcompid = OwnerCompanyLog.olog_companyid 
    where inlt_companyid=5 
    Order By inlt_childcompid
```

I want to use `inlt_percent * inlt_effectinterest)/100` in my C# code:

```
 entity.ParentCompany = new List<Company>();
     while (parentCompanyReader.Read())
            {
    ParentCompany.Effect = parentCompanyReader["eff"].ToString();
    entity.ParentCompany.Add(ParentCompany);
            }

            parentCompanyReader.Close();
```

But I got the error above.

Comment: its not a sql error..the problwm seems to be in your c# array 'parentCompanyReader',  ...you need to post your c# code here

Answer (score 0):

the problem is only with calculated field. The above comment is absolutely correct. It could be your parentCompanyReader class that has the error. Meanwhile could you try few things to confirm the error.

Move the eff column to some middle. It could be that your parentCompanyReader would not be able to deal with only a limited number of column.

Also what is "eff" here, a column ? Also put a AS after the calculated column.

```
Select (inlt_percent * inlt_effectinterest)/100)eff AS EFF, OwnerCompanyLog.olog_name,inlt_companyid,inlt_childcompid,inlt_effectinterest,inlt_percent,inlt_sharetype,inlt_shares,inlt_childbase,inlt_effdate
```

Note : these are just arrows in dark !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it with index rather than column name .

```
     while (parentCompanyReader.Read())
        {
        ParentCompany.Effect = Convert.ToInt32(parentCompanyReader[5]);
        entity.ParentCompany.Add(ParentCompany);
        }

        parentCompanyReader.Close();
```

Im assuming that the calculated field returns an integer

and also make sure u use using statement so that incase if there is an error then connection will be closed and disposed